# .css() method is not called and <div> is hence not updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video, jplayer

***Functionality:***

I have set the following video to be in fullscreen mode when clicked. Therefore, the intial video Container Css style is : `<div id="Journal_Video" style="position:absolute; left: 120px; top: 180px;" class="jp-video jp-video-750p" role="application" aria-label="media player"></div>` . Hence, when user clicks, the video will expand to fullScreen and when user cicks on the video again, the video will revert back to its original size and style.

What has been done:

I have managed to set the video to expand and revert back to it original screen size.

I have attached the following code for your perusal:

```
<script>
//Journal Video
$("#Journal_Video").jPlayer({
ready: function() {
var self = this;
var fullScreen = $(self).jPlayer("option", "fullScreen");

$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
  m4v: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/YE7VzlLtp-4"
}).jPlayer("play");
$(".jp-jplayer video").click(function() {

  if (fullScreen = !fullScreen) {
    $("#Journal_Video").css({
      "top": "0",
      "left": "0"
    });
    $(self).jPlayer("option", {
      "fullScreen": fullScreen
    });
  } else if (fullScreen == fullScreen) {
    $(self).jPlayer("option", {
      "fullScreen": false
    });
    $("#Journal_Video").css({
      "top": "180",
      "left": "120"
    });
  }

  });
   },
  swfPath: "javascript",
  supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v",
  loop: true,
  useStateClassSkin: true,
  autoBlur: false,
  smoothPlayBar: true,
  keyEnabled: true,
  sizeFull: {
    top: 0,
    cssClass: "jp-video-750p",
  },
  size: {
    width: 1200,
    height: 750
  }
  });
  $("#Journal_Video").show();
  </script>

  <div id="Journal_Video" style="position:absolute; left: 120px; top: 180px;" class="jp-video jp-video-750p" role="application" aria-label="media player"></div>
```

***Issue:***

When user clicks on the fullScreen Video to return back to the original video. The Css Styling of

```
$("#Journal_Video").css({
  "top": "180",
  "left": "120"
});
```

at `else if (fullScreen == fullScreen) {...}` is not called.

Therefore, I dont understand why I was able to set the CSS settings when expanding the screen, however am not able to set the Css styling when closing the expanded fullscreen.

Please help.

Comment: I'm getting an error like: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jPlayer is not a function` based on, I'm guessing, the line `$("#Journal_Video").jPlayer` and the fact that `jPlayer` isn't a defined method for a normal jQuery object. Can you provide a working example (like a fiddle) showing that the error is where you think it is?

Comment: @Anthony Thanks for the reply adn the suggestion. I reckon that I need to provide the jQuery file for jPlayer: `<script src="javascript/jplayer.playlist.min.js"></script><script src="javascript/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>`. Secondly, I have managed to find out why the default CSS setting for video container is not being called. I have to add in `px` behind all the dimension value. All the small errors that lead to a big malfuncitons

Answer (score 0):

change

```
else if (fullScreen == fullScreen;)
```

to

```
else if (fullScreen == fullScreen)
```

Comment: sorry,t hat was typo. Else, the same problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be setting the fullScreen value to be false in `(fullScreen = !fullScreen)` therefore the else if conditional would never be true. Do you mean `(fullScreen !== fullScreen)`?